# Injecting image content into webkit load

Tags: c, webkit, gtk, webkitgtk

Inside my WebKitGTK+ widget, I want to transparently replace some of the images of an HTML page with different image data I hold **in memory**.

According to the documentation at http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-resource-request-starting, I've hooked into this signal, which allows the request URI to be changed, but what I really want is to leave it unchanged but generate my own response.

I've tried filling out the WebKitWebResource parameter, and filling out the SoupMessage response from the WebKitNetworkRequest to no avail. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out one way to do it: replacing the request URL with "data:image/jpeg;base64,[inline data]".

Will do for me.